# jquery ajax Find out What caused the Error loading XML document

Tags: ajax, xml-parsing

In my page i use the following code, and it shows the error message "Error loading XML document". How can i find out what actually caused the error?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'document.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error loading XML document');
    },
    success: function(xml){
        // do something with xml
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` is not working in a simple html you should use it on a server like wamp/xamp or host the page

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the template using a `file://` or `C:/`, it remains faithful to the error message because they are not `http://`

So you can install a web server on your local pc like xammp or wamp if you are Mac user intale the Mamp or upload the template else where and use json or change the URL to `http://example.com/path/to/` model xml must be run on a server so that the error is not displayed again.